# bash script using xargs and curl(how to echo parsing argument)

Tags: bash, curl, xargs

```
sed -e 's/,$//' -e 'y/,/:/' myips.txt | xargs  -P 5 -I XX  curl -skd --connect-timeout 10 --max-time 10 http://XX/
```

myips.txt is gonna be

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
```

I save the output in a file but i cant figure out how to echo the ip at the begining of each otput

the command is gonna be curl -skd --connect-timeout 10 --max-time 10 http://127.0.0.1 and the output lets say something like a random webpage

giving the fact that i have more than 50 ips to look into, i cant figure out witch ip outputs what

for example the output is gonna be

```
`Error 404: Not Found Error 404: Not Found `
```

and i want it to be

```
127.0.0.1 Error 404: Not Found 127.0.0.2 Error 404: Not Found
```

or even nicer would be better

```
127.0.0.1 Error 404: Not Found 
===================================    
127.0.0.2 Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: You are lucky that with _more than 50 ips to look into_, five `curl` invocations running in parallel and all writing to STDOUT, you never saw these outputs intermixed - presumably all webpages are quite short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/,$//' -e 'y/,/:/' myips.txt \
    | xargs  -P 5 -I XX \
        sh -c '
            printf "%s " XX;
            curl -skd --connect-timeout 10 --max-time 10 http://XX/
            echo ===================================
        '
```

This is actually not related to curl, here's a demo with `echo`:

```
sed -e 's/,$//' -e 'y/,/:/' myips.txt \
    | xargs  -P 5 -I XX \
        sh -c '
            printf "%s " XX;
            echo "Error 404: Not Found";
            echo ===================================
        '
```

Output with your `myips.txt`:

```
127.0.0.1 Error 404: Not Found
===================================
127.0.0.2 Error 404: Not Found
===================================
127.0.0.3 Error 404: Not Found
===================================
```